# returning undefined from map function - code wars

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been given an array full of integers and want to create a new array with the averages of each integer-number and his follower. To achieve this I have tried to use the `map` function.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.map(function(a, b){
   return (a + b / 2);
});
```

I believe that this is working, as if I run this in the console everything works as expected, however the issue is that it is returning undefined where the challenge is set. The [challenge is set here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/averages-of-numbers/train/javascript). Is there something stupid that I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the callback parameters for [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which is the element itself, the index and the reference to the array. Then assign the result to a variable and skip the first element, because you get one more element as you need.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = arr.map(function(a, i, aa) {
        return (aa[i - 1] + a) / 2;
    });

result.shift();
console.log(result);
```

Another possible solution with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which maps more your try.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    result = [];

arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    result.push((a + b) / 2);
    return b;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

a basic solution might be with iteration.

```
foo = function(arr){ 
  var result=[];
  for( var i=0; i<arr.length-1; i++) {
    result.push((arr[i]+arr[i+1])/2)
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: there is a syntax error in your answer. Thanks for answering tho :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should understand map() or reduce() or filter